# Divide words depending on first character

Tags: php, regex

I have a paragraph, What i want to group each words depending on the first character and sort the group by other character.

**Sample text:**

```
$text = "Why end might ask civil again spoil. She dinner she our horses depend. Remember at children by reserved to vicinity. In affronting unreserved delightful simplicity ye. Law own advantage furniture continual sweetness bed agreeable perpetual. Oh song well four only head busy it. Afford son she had lively living. Tastes lovers myself too formal season our valley boy. Lived it their their walls might to by young.";
```

Expected result for the first sentence-

Why end might ask civil again spoil

```
a => again, ask
c => civil
e => end
m => might
s => spoil
w => Why
```

Comment: And what's expected result exactly?

Comment: I need to group the paragraph with each word and also sort the group by other characters.

Comment: @Shafizadeh, i updated my question what i need.

Comment: Ok, but `a => ask, again` is odd ..! You put `aks` and `again` into one key of that array because they start with `a`. Am I right?

Comment: Typo mistake, I will update it now.

Comment: You don't need a regex at all, why are you seeking for one?

Comment: This can be a clue https://3v4l.org/uh4V4

Comment: I don't know, i think that may help to group and sort.

Comment: @Shafizadeh, is it not possible to show as i want???

Comment: Everything is possible, but I'm not a PHP expert. Maybe other people help you out.

Comment: @Shafizadeh, Thank you for your help.

Comment: what do you want to do at end of a sentence? i.e. merge them in array at end, or keep each sentence as separate results in array ?

Comment: I want multi-dimensional array like: `array(a => array(again, ask), ... )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways to do it.... I just chose one I find slightly more interesting (than just "gimme script" ;-))

```
<?php
// see http://docs.php.net/splheap
class StrcasecmpHeap extends SplHeap {
    protected function compare ($a,$b) { return strcasecmp($b,$a); }
}
$text = "Why end might ask civil again spoil. She dinner she our horses depend. Remember at children by reserved to vicinity. In affronting unreserved delightful simplicity ye. Law own advantage furniture continual sweetness bed agreeable perpetual. Oh song well four only head busy it. Afford son she had lively living. Tastes lovers myself too formal season our valley boy. Lived it their their walls might to by young.";

// create
$result = [];
// see http://docs.php.net/preg_split
foreach( preg_split('![^a-zA-Z]+!', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $word ) {
    $char = strtolower($word[0]);
    if ( !isset($result[$char]) ) {
        $result[$char] = new StrcasecmpHeap;
    }
    $result[$char]->insert($word);
}

// print
foreach( $result as $char=>$list ) {
    echo "--- $char ---", PHP_EOL;
    foreach($list as $word ) {
        echo ' ', $word, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

This will keep doublets like e.g.

> --- s ---
>  season
>  **She**
>  **she**
>  **she**
>  simplicity

or

```
<?php
$text = "Why end might ask civil again spoil. She dinner she our horses depend. Remember at children by reserved to vicinity. In affronting unreserved delightful simplicity ye. Law own advantage furniture continual sweetness bed agreeable perpetual. Oh song well four only head busy it. Afford son she had lively living. Tastes lovers myself too formal season our valley boy. Lived it their their walls might to by young.";

// build
$result = [];
foreach( preg_split('![^a-zA-Z]+!', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $word ) {
    // here goes the case-sensitivity; it's all lower-case from now on....
    $word = strtolower($word);
    $char = $word[0];
    // not storing as the element's value but the key
    // takes care of doublets
    $result[$char][$word] = true;
}

// get keys & sort
$result = array_map(
    function($e) {
        // remember? The actual words have been stored as the keys
        $e = array_keys($e);
        usort($e, 'strcasecmp');
        return $e;
    },
    $result
);


// print
var_export($result);
```

Comment: Thank you, But i need it as a multi-dimensional array like: `array(a => array(again, ask), ... )`, is it possible from your script?

Comment: It's an array of SPLHeaps, i.e. an array of iterators. Is there a (real) difference for your use case?

Comment: is it possible to convert it a simple array? I don't understand heap, I can little work with simple array.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible. But then it's probably easier to start with arrays right away (boooooring ;-)) See update.

Comment: Thanks a lot, One more thing, Which one is best? **Heap** or normal array.

Comment: It depends (you didn't really expect another answer, did you? ;-)). I just chose it to maybe motivate you to look into such standard data structures like heaps, queues, search trees et al. Just look them up in wikipedia or similar and while you're at it take a glimpse at the O-notation (O(n), O(n log n) and so on)- that's where you will find the/a difference between both implementations ;-) Memory consumption would be another general factor - but not in this case (I think...)

Comment: And juuuuust in case you're really starting to dig through the O-thingy: A standard php array is really a [hashmap/hashtable](https://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html), [its standard string hash function is DJBX33A](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/hashtables/hash_algorithm.html) and sort/usort/... are (iirc) [quicksort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) implementations.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is built around a regex which splits the already sorted words into phrases by initial letter.

- `(\w)`: a capturing group matching any letter (technically any "word" character), which matches the first letter in a word, then
- `.*?`: the smallest possible number of characters (could just be from one word, or from several) followed by
- `($| (?!\\1))`: the very end of the text **or** a space **not** followed by the same letter as the initial capturing group.

```
$text = "Why end might ask civil again spoil. She dinner she our horses"
    . " depend. Remember at children by reserved to vicinity. In affronting"
    . " unreserved delightful simplicity ye. Law own advantage furniture"
    . " continual sweetness bed agreeable perpetual. Oh song well four only"
    . " head busy it. Afford son she had lively living. Tastes lovers"
    . " myself too formal season our valley boy. Lived it their their walls"
    . " might to by young.";

// Split the text into individual words and sort them, case insensitively.
$words = preg_split("[\W+]", $text);
natcasesort($words);

// Join the sorted words back together and break them into phrases by
// initial letter.
preg_match_all("[(\w).*?($| (?!\\1))]i", implode(" ", $words), $matches);

// Arrange the phrases into an array keyed by lower-case initial letter,
// split them back into an array of words.
$words = array_combine(
    array_map("strtolower", $matches[1]),
    array_map(function($phrase){ return explode(" ", trim($phrase)); },
              $matches[0]));

var_dump($words);

/*
array (size=19)
  'a' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string 'advantage' (length=9)
      1 => string 'Afford' (length=6)
      2 => string 'affronting' (length=10)
      3 => string 'again' (length=5)
      4 => string 'agreeable' (length=9)
      5 => string 'ask' (length=3)
      6 => string 'at' (length=2)
  'b' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'bed' (length=3)
      1 => string 'boy' (length=3)
      2 => string 'busy' (length=4)
      3 => string 'by' (length=2)
      4 => string 'by' (length=2)
  ...
 */
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer.